# Is AdaBoost an online classificer only?

Tags: machine-learning, boosting, adaboost, c

I have been using [CControl](https://github.com/DanielMartensson/CControl/) library for classify data.
As I understand AdaBoost, it's an online non-linear classifier algorithm and not an algorithm, such as SVM, that gives you weights back were you can use them later to classify new unkown data? Or does AdaBoost train weights were I can use them later?

I have made an example that you can run online.

https://onlinegdb.com/a3dVQ8row

https://godbolt.org/z/MqGz9svsj

Comment: AdaBoost definitely can be used to classify new online data, a trained model can be saved to be used later. See also [the example code block in the `scikit-learn` documentation ](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.html) for an example on how to classify new data.

Comment: @Oxbowerce Thank you. According to `Stat Quest`, the `AdaBoost` algorithm is more like a online classfier. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LsK-xG1cLYA&ab_channel=StatQuestwithJoshStarmer